# Python/Django IDE for Solaris

Tags: python, django, ide, solaris

Could anyone tell me a well-round Python & Django IDE fully compatible with Solaris?. I'm only aware of Netbeans but as far as I know It does not have support for Django and it lacks also of important features for Python like code completion.

Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry but `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` so this type of question is off-topic for here

Comment: I use Sublime Text for Django development. There are many packages you can install that have code completion, even for Django.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest use www.pythonanywhere.com

You can build and host your Django app there for free, it supports Python 2.7 and 3.4, most recent Django versions ( 1.4 to 1.8) and has virtualenv support so you can change whatever you like. It even comes preloaded with many useful libraries.
It doesn't support text completion in the editor but I don't think that's a deal breaker considering how Python is as it is a lot more concise than most other languages.

Having it on pythonanywhere lets you test it and debug it pretty fast. Also being a cloud solution it's 100% portable and you can develop it on any device that lets you access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse supports Solaris, so you could use [pydev](http://pydev.org/). I prefer pyCharm, but pydev is actually pretty good, even if you don't like Eclipse.